# Mouseover Image On Buttons In FMX XE2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2

How to make a mouseover image for button ? 
I used to make in FMX 2 buttons, and fill it with bitmap. But its owful .
I found property `IsMouseOver`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
if Button1.IsMouseOver  then
begin
  Button1.Text:='yes';
end
else
begin
  Button1.Text:='nono';
end;
end;
```

But , i realy dont understand how to use containers, i only want to change fill ( my bitmap) by the method written before. Can someone give a simple code?

Or maybe its easier to make in VCL ?

Answer (score 2):

Put two separate `TImage` controls on the button (drag them onto the button in the Structure View):

[image: Structure View image]

Size them to fit the button, and give each a separate image using the `MultiResBitmap` property editor.

Create an event handler for one of the `TImage` components for the `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` events, and then assign those handlers to both of the `TImage` components:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Visible := False;
  Image2.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Visible := True;
  Image2.Visible := False;
end;
```